Button no tiene las mismas dimensiones que los input aunque haya especificado las mismas medidas


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Mulish:ital,wght@0,200..1000;1,200..1000&display=swap');

body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.main-container {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.main-container form {
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.title {
    font-family: "Mulish", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #04146c;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

input {
    font-family: "Mulish", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #414166;
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

button {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #0a2ff1;
    color: white;
    font-family: "Mulish", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
}

a {
    font-family: "Mulish", sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18.6px;
    color: #0a2ff1;
}

hr {
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 500px;
}

button:hover {
    background-color: #243fc4;
    color: rgb(226, 216, 216);
}

a:hover {
    color: #3f5ae2;
}
<body>
    <div class="main-container">
        <form action="" method="post">
            <legend class="title">Iniciar Sesión</legend>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Introduzca el nombre de usuario" minlength="5" maxlength="20" required>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Introduzca la contraseña" minlength="8" maxlength="16" required>
            <button type="submit">Iniciar sesión</button>
            <hr>
            <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">¿No se puede iniciar sesión?</a>
            <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank" rel="noopener">Regístrese para crear una cuenta nueva</a>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>



Estoy practicando HTML y CSS. Me encuentro armando un pequeño inicio de sesión que tiene un título, dos inputs (usuario y contraseña), un botón, un hr y dos enlaces. El botón y el hr no alcanzan a igualar las dimensiones de los input, aunque todos tengan especificadas las mismas medidas.
Viendo desde el inspector de elementos, puedo notar que los input tienen algunos pixeles de más que se han agregado de forma automática.
En la imagen busco mostrar el problema que estoy presentando con las dimensiones del elemento button respecto de los input, ya que no estoy logrando igualar las medidas para que el login pueda mostrarse ordenado.

Soy pésimo en CSS, por lo que espero que alguien elabore una respuesta mejor para tu pregunta (y tendrá mi +1). Parece que el problema es porque HTML 5 cambió la forma de renderizar el box-model y agrega un padding externo de forma automática. Para resolver, de momento, puedes usar el modelo clásico colocando box-sizing: border-box; dentro del selector de input { ... } en el CSS. Más información: MDN - The Box Model, Box Sizing

@aeportugal Excelente!! me sirvió perfectamente, muchas gracias por la ayuda, saludos!!
